# Referesh page using jquery rails

Tags: jquery

Actually, I want to do current page refresh in every 30 seconds with this.

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href);
```

After that I have to stop the refresh as well.

Comment: `refresh in every 30 seconds` then `stop the refresh`. Why and how?

Comment: Its an order page so if any new order came my dispatchers has to see that new order that's why page's refresh in 30 seconds, and if at any time my dispatcher want to stop the page refresh then they can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try with this->

```
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    $("#div_wrapper").load(window.location.href);
}, 30000); // For reloading

$("#btnlabels").click(function(e) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
});
```

Where btnLabel is an id for stop refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). By default, there is no item `window.location.href` in the storage. So, when the page is loaded, you can use `setTimeout` to refresh the page in 30s.

```
var item = localStorage.getItem('window.location.href');
if (!item) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.replace(window.location.href);
    }, 30000);
}
```

During that time, if the button like `Stop refresh` is clicked, we set new item `window.location.href` with the value `true` to the storage. BTW, you can stop the refresh.

```
localStorage.setItem('window.location.href', 'true');
```

Then, when the page is loaded again, because there is an item in the storage, the `setTimeout` function wouldn't be called.